# Trouble understanding Riemann Integral and Limits

Tags: calculus

Let p>0. Using Riemann's Integral find the limit. 
Here is the problem :
[pic http://www.upload.ee/image/3755496/Riemannintegral.png](http://www.upload.ee/image/3755496/Riemannintegral.png)

The problem is , i don't know how to start or what should i do. 
I can't really understand this chapter from my book and there are no examples ... 
Also calculus books written in english are hard for me to understand , so try to use simple words explaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write

$$\frac{1^p+2^p+...+n^p}{n^{p+1}}=\frac{1}{n} \left( \left( \frac{1}{n}\right)^p + \left( \frac{2}{n}\right)^p + ... + \left( \frac{n}{n}\right)^p \right)= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\left( \frac k n\right)^p$$

This is a [Riemann sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum) and, when $n \to \infty$, it converges to $\int_0^1 x^p \, \mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{p+1}$.

Comment: Well okay thanks for that , but I will probably go and ask the teacher, how we go from limit of a sum to a Newton-Leibniz integral ... do you know any good calculus books that could help me with this ? 

Also , about bounds , could i also use like -1 and 0 ? I understand that it is |b-a| and a<b ?

Comment: Depends on your level. Apostol (Calculus I & II) covers the first two years of university I believe, and is well know, but it's also very expensive, and probably "high level". You should ask your teacher, he will give you adapted references, and if you have access to a university library, you will find much there.

Answer (score 1):

Recognize the function evaluated at some partition of some interval...

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\;\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac kn\right)^p=\int\limits_0^1x^p\,dx=1\;\ldots$$

The first equality above stems from the fact that we **know** that $\;x^p\;$ is integrable on $\;[0,1]\;$ and thus we can choose the partition and the points in each subinterval as we wish to evaluate the Riemann sums.

Comment: I think arbautjc had correct answer but thank you :)

Comment: I think both our answers are practically identical, @La'tel, but you're free to choose and accept what you want.